# Basic Regex help needed

Tags: c#, regex, winforms, visual-studio-2013

I'm really new to programming and haven't come across Regex until now, I am looking to restrict textbox input to double class values only and came across this:

```
    `Regex regex = new Regex("[^0-9-]+");
     TextP1_TextChanged = regex.IsMatch(TextP1.Text);`
```

I want to implement into my program and am assuming it occurs under the `TextChanged` event, but I don't actually have the knowledge to implement regex and so am just looking for any help.

Update

I've implemented `TryParse` but am looking to accept decimal numbers with or without `0` in front, i.e. `0.234` or `.234`. My new code is this:

```
    private void TextP1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        bool isDouble = Double.TryParse(TextP1.Text, out P1);
        if(isDouble == false)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Text box only accepts positive number values", "Text entered into P1 is invalid", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why not just test for a parseable double using `double.TryParse` or `double.Parse` with a `try..catch`?

Comment: @Psi is right.  You don't need (or want) Regex for this, and your question is way too broad anyway, as it's asking not just about Regex but event handlers and how to hook code you found on the Internet into your application.

Comment: I've now implemented this and it works, however I need to be able to accept `.0234` as well as `0.234` is there a way of doing this?

Comment: When you say you've implemented this, do you mean you used the regex code you shared or you used `double.TryParse`?  I tried `double.TryParse(".0234", out val)` and it worked just fine.

Comment: @adv12 I've update my question to clarify

Comment: `double.TryParse` returns `true` on both `"0.0234"` and `".0234"` equally, which is what @adv12 was trying to say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this regular expression `[0-9]*\.[0-9]*`. The * means 0-9 can occur 0 to x times.

You could use [regexr](http://regexr.com/) to test regular expression in a fast way.